# HTML-Table combine two filter scripts

Tags: javascript, html

I have two filters, one is a =>greater than or =<less than for one column and the other is a =>greater than and from an input box for a different column.

How can I combine into one code so they work together?

Thanks

```js
function search() {
    // Declare variables
    var select, option, filter, table, tr, td_Ht, td_unf, i, cellValue;
    var un_fact = document.getElementById('l_Oad')
     select = document.getElementById('column_Height');
         option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    document.getElementById('value').value = option.text;
        document.getElementById('text').value = option.value;
    filter = parseInt(option.value);
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td_Ht = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
      td_unf = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
      if (td_Ht) {
        cellValue = parseInt(td_Ht.innerHTML);
        if ((cellValue >= option.text) && (cellValue <= option.value)) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  function search_UnF() {
    // Declare variables
    var filter, table, tr, td_unf, i, cellValue;
    var un_fact = document.getElementById('l_oad')
    filter = parseInt(un_fact.value);
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td_unf = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
      if (td_unf) {
        cellValue = parseInt(td_unf.innerHTML);
        if (cellValue >= filter) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  margin-left:-5px;
  margin-right:-5px;
}
  
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid rgb(8, 18, 1);
  border-collapse: collapse;  
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  th, td {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgb(30, 131, 5);
  }
  tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: rgb(36, 84, 25);
  }       

#column_Height{
 width:60px;   
}
```

```html
<h2>COLUMNS</h2>

<label for="column_Height">Column Height:</label>
<select id="column_Height" onChange="search()" ;>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="90">89</option>
    <option value="96">90</option>
    <option value="102">96</option>
    <option value="120">102</option>
    <option value="144">120</option>
    <option value="168">144</option>
    <option value="192">168</option>
    <option value="216">192</option>
    <option value="216">216</option>
</select> 
<label for="value">Between</label>
<input type="text" id="value" size="4" disabled>
<label for="text">and</label>
<input type="text" id="text" size="4" disabled>
<label for="l_oad">Enter Unfactored</label>
<input type="text" id="l_oad" onkeyup="search_UnF()" placeholder="Unfactored.." title="Load" size="15">

<h2>Posts and Plate/Saddles</h2>
<p>Post selector and top Plates for spliced beams:</p>

<div class="row">
<div class="column">
<table id="myTable">
<tr class="header">
<th style="width:25%;">PRODUCT</th>
<th style="width:12.5%;">UNFACT</th>
<th style="width:12.5%;">EXT</th>
<th style="width:35%;">BASE/TOP</th>
<th style="width:10%;">HeiGHT</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>STS-7.5 - NS</td>
<td>11190</td>
<td>7' 6"</td>
<td>B 4"x4" / T 3.5"x5.25"</td>
<td>90</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>STS-8.0 - NS</td>
<td>10175</td>
<td>8'0"</td>
<td>B 4"x4" / T 3.5"x5.25*</td>
<td>96</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>STS-8.5</td>
<td>9200</td>
<td>8' 6"</td>
<td>B 4"x4" / T 3.5"x5.25"</td>
<td>102</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>STS-10</td>
<td>7050</td>
<td>10' 0"</td>
<td>B 4"x4" / T 3.5"x5.25"</td>
<td>120</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>STL-7.4 - NS</td>
<td>17080</td>
<td>7' 5"</td>
<td>Larger Top Plate Req'd.</td>
<td>89</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>STL-8.0 - NS</td>
<td>15720</td>
<td>8' 0"</td>
<td>4"x6" 5"x7"</td>
<td>96</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>STL-8.5</td>
<td>14400</td>
<td>8' 6"</td>
<td>4"x6' 5"x7"</td>
<td>102</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>STL-10</td>
<td>11300</td>
<td>10' 0"</td>
<td>4"x6" 5"x7"</td>
<td>120</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>STM1-7.4 - NS</td>
<td>26070</td>
<td>7' 5"</td>
<td>4"x8" 6"x8"</td>
<td>89</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>STM1-8.0 - NS</td>
<td>24390</td>
<td>8' 0"</td>
<td>4 x8 6 x8</td>
<td>96</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>STM1-8.5</td>
<td>22730</td>
<td>8' 6"</td>
<td>4"x8" 6"x8"</td>
<td>102</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>STM1-10</td>
<td>18300</td>
<td>10' 0"</td>
<td>4"x8", 6"x8"</td>
<td>120</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STM1-12</td>
<td>13970</td>
<td>12' 0"</td>
<td>4"x8" 6"x8"</td>
<td>144</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STM1-14</td>
<td>10830</td>
<td>14' 0"</td>
<td>4"x8" 6" x8"</td>
<td>168</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STM2-8.0 - NS</td>
<td>34140</td>
<td>8' 0"</td>
<td>4"x8" 6"x8"</td>
<td>96</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STM2-8.5</td>
<td>31730</td>
<td>8' 6"</td>
<td>4"x8" 6"x8"</td>
<td>102</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STM2-10</td>
<td>25600</td>
<td>10' 0"</td>
<td>4"x8" 6"x8"</td>
<td>120</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STM2-12</td>
<td>19390</td>
<td>12' 0"</td>
<td>4"x8" 6"x8"</td>
<td>144</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STM2-14</td>
<td>15000</td>
<td>14' 0"</td>
<td>4"x8" 6"x8"</td>
<td>168</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STM2-16</td>
<td>11840</td>
<td>16' 0"</td>
<td>4"x8" 6"x8"</td>
<td>192</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STH-8.0 - NS</td>
<td>48200</td>
<td>8' 0"</td>
<td>B6"x6" / T7"x10"</td>
<td>96</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STH-8.5</td>
<td>45500</td>
<td>8' 6"</td>
<td>B 6"x6" / T 7"x10"</td>
<td>102</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STH-10</td>
<td>37740</td>
<td>10' 0"</td>
<td>B 6"x6" / T 7"x10"</td>
<td>120</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STH-12</td>
<td>29640</td>
<td>12' 0"</td>
<td>B 6"x6" / T7"x10"</td>
<td>144</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STH-14</td>
<td>23390</td>
<td>14' 0"</td>
<td>B 6"x6" / T 7"x10"</td>
<td>168</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STH-16</td>
<td>18750</td>
<td>16' 0"</td>
<td>B 6"x6" / T7"x10"</td>
<td>192</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STXH-8.0 - NS</td>
<td>80070</td>
<td>8' 0"</td>
<td>Larger Top Plate Req'd</td>
<td>96</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STXH-8.5</td>
<td>76210</td>
<td>8' 6"</td>
<td>B 8"x8" / T7"x14"</td>
<td>102</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STXH-10</td>
<td>65090</td>
<td>10' 0"</td>
<td>B 8"x8" / T 7"x14"</td>
<td>120</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STXH-12</td>
<td>52300</td>
<td>12' 0"</td>
<td>B 8"x8" / T7"x14"</td>
<td>144</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STXH-14</td>
<td>42200</td>
<td>14' 0"</td>
<td>B 8"x8" / T 7"x14"</td>
<td>168</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STXH-16</td>
<td>34340</td>
<td>16' 0"</td>
<td>B 8"x8* / T 7nx14"</td>
<td>192</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>STXH-18</td>
<td>28170</td>
<td>18' 0"</td>
<td>B 8"x8" / T 7"x14"</td>
<td>216</td>

</tr>


</table>
```

Comment: If an element passes both conditions, it ah passes both conditions. When seiving solid material, one runs it through filter after filter after filter. Just do the same here. Check that the first condition is satisfied (if not, bail) then check if the second condition is also satisfied.
Unsure of what's presenting the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create separated functions that tell you when to filter a row, or not. Each function has the row and other parameters needed to check the filter:

```
function filterSearch(tr, text, value) {
   let td_Ht = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
   let td_unf = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
   if (td_Ht) {
     let cellValue = parseInt(td_Ht.innerHTML);
     return cellValue < text || cellValue > value;
   }
}

function filterUnF(tr, filter) {
  if (isNaN(filter))
    return false;
       
  let td_unf = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
  if (td_unf) {
    let cellValue = parseInt(td_unf.innerHTML);
    return cellValue < filter);
  }
}
```

Then, you iterate all rows and, for each row, you check if it passes the filter or not:

```
function search() {
  // Declare variables
  var select, option, filter, table, tr, td_Ht, td_unf, i, cellValue;
  var un_fact = document.getElementById('l_oad')
  select = document.getElementById('column_Height');
  option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
  document.getElementById('value').value = option.text;
  document.getElementById('text').value = option.value;
  filter = parseInt(option.value);
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  filterUn = parseInt(un_fact.value);

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td_Ht = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
    td_unf = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

    var filter = filterSearch(tr[i], option.text, option.value) || 
        filterUnF(tr[i], filterUn);
    tr[i].style.display =  filter ? "none" : "";
  }
}
```

NOTE: In your code `document.getElementById('l_Oad')` you are using a zero instead letter o.

In the for, I start at 1 index because I know that 0 is the header.

Comment: Thanks, this does work but I was hoping to have the table filter when the height was selected, and then filter as you were typing in the loads. Your code only starts filtering when you start entering in the load box.

Comment: You must change the function to execute on keyup: onkeyup="search_UnF(). Must call to search().